# What is valid HTTP error code if server does not support async

Tags: http, http-status-codes

Our server can support both async and sync HTTP requests. However processing of async request depends on a number of internal parameter and "can-not-be-supported" in some instance.

Client requests for async processing of request using prefer header.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240#page-8

What shall be the proper response code by server if async is not supported? Shall it be HTTP 501 not implemented?

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.2

Note that same request can be processed synchronously if customer does not include prefer header. So can this be also treated as 4xx error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shall it be HTTP 501 not implemented?

No.

> So can this be also treated as 4xx error?

Not at all.

> What shall be the proper response code by server if async is not supported?

Ignore it and move on. See what the [RFC 7240](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240) says:

> A server that does not recognize or is unable to comply with particular preference tokens in the `Prefer` header field of a request MUST ignore those tokens and continue processing instead of signaling an error.